# "Hystrix stream is not generating for my spring mvc application"

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a simple Spring MVC application. For that application I have Implemented **Circuit Breaker Pattern** using @EnableCircuitBreaker Annotation. It is working fine. But While trying to generate the hystrix stream it showing 404 error. Can anyone please help me out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hystrix stream (`/hystrix.stream`) is only enabled if you have spring boot actuator dependency. Please try to add the below dependency into your pom or gradle build file.

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator
```

---

Updated @ 2017/06/26

If your application is not based on spring boot, you need to configure `HystrixMetricsStreamServlet` by yourself. Because /hystrix.stream is auto-configured by spring cloud netflix and it is based on spring boot.

First, you need to add dependency of `com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream` into your application.
Second, you should `HystrixMetricsStreamServlet` servlet into `web.xml` like below.

```
 <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>HystrixMetricsStreamServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>HystrixMetricsStreamServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.metrics.eventstream.HystrixMetricsStreamServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HystrixMetricsStreamServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hystrix.stream</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping
```

If you find the details about how to configure `HystrixMetricsStreamServlet` in your web application [here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-metrics-event-stream).

Comment: If I place spring-boot-starter-actuator in my pom.xml my project artifact is going to fail.

FYI: My application is in Spring MVC. No boot dependencies. So I have added spring-boot-starter-web, then also I'm getting issue while running the code.

Comment: I've updated my answer because you are not using spring-boot.